# visual studio 2012 debug windows 8

Tags: windows-8, permissions, iis, debug, visual-studio-2012

I run a local `IIS` server to develop a website and it works. If I try to debug however it stated "Unable to start debugging on the web server. You do not have permissions to debug the web server process." as explained [on this site](http://hellowahab.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-you-do-not-have-permissions-to-debug-the-web-server-process/). It also has the solution on there, run as administrator.

The problem is that I also have to publish the website to a remote computer. I've create a networkmap to the correct folder (drive `W`). Publishing to this drive only works if I dont run `VS` as administrator. As admin it gives the error `The path 'W:\' does not exist or you do not have access`

Now I'd like to do both without having to restart `VS` everytime in a different mode.

Now I tried the other option in the first error message, which is to run `IIS` as the same user. I changed the application pool user and now when I look at the taskmanager both `devenv.exe` and `w3wp.exe` run as `h.delsing`, but it still doesnt work without explicitly giving administrator priviledges. Do I need to change something else to run both `IIS` and `VS` as the same user?

Another option would be to allow access to `W` as admin. Strange thing is that if I run another program as admin (totalcommander) I still have access to the `W` drive. So i have no clue on how to do this.

The same setup worked fine on `Windows 7` which uses the same authentication structure as far as I know. Only difference is that `Windows 8` is linked to my live account. I sure hope that is not what causing the problem, as I read that Windows is a [little sketchy when it comes to what account it is actualy using](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/19/Windows-8-Live-Accounts-and-the-actual-Windows-Account).

So in short:

- How can I run `IIS` and `VS` as the same user without admin for debugging?
- Or how can I allow access to the `W` drive as admin from `VS`?

Comment: I willing to almost guarantee the reason your having this problem is because your account is linked to your Microsoft Account.  This on a domain?

Comment: The reason the W drive didnt work, is that it wasnt connected yet. I had to run the explorer once as administrator and access the W drive. Then the connection was made and it works in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use the full version of IIS for your project?

I think you could try IIS Express instead of the full IIS, this runs locally on your developer machine and allows debugging without running Visual Studio in admin mode, this might be a way to both get access to the network publishing and local debugging.

Have a look at [Using IIS Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.ASPX#bkmk_usingiisexpress) to do configure your web Project to run under IISExpress when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Process Monitor to see what user account is being used to access the W:\ drive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If it's a permissions issue then knowing which user is trying to access the W:\ can help resolve the problem.